# merging an empty pandas Series with inner join does not give null result

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I define the following:

```
s = pd.Series(range(10))
s2 = pd.Series([])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,2)), columns = ['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[]})
```

When I use the pandas concat function, it mostly gives me results I would expect:

```
In [14]: pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
Out[14]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []

In [16]: pd.concat([df, s], axis=1, join='inner')
Out[16]: 
          a         b  0
0  0.482953  0.690403  0
1  0.566467  0.934391  1
2  0.876860  0.075017  2
3  0.875775  0.704174  3
```

But when I merge two series, one of which is empty, I do not get a length-zero result:

```
In [23]: pd.concat([s, s2], axis=1, join='inner')
Out[23]: 
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

This seems like incorrect behavior to me unless it's somehow a feature I don't understand. Is this a bug?

Comment: I have also tested to see if this holds true for a non-integer index or column names. Neither seems to affect this result. In case it matters, I'm on pandas 0.14.1

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or feature, but what are you trying to accomplish?  Note that axis=1 is sort of a strange concept here since series are essentially 1-dimensional.  Also, I wonder if merge might be what you are looking for.  But again, it isn't real clear to me what the point would be of intentionally using concat on an empty series or dataset in the first place.

Comment: I'm creating a dataframe from the intersection of two Series. For downstream processing I want to have them in one object. I'm not really intentionally using it to handle empty Series objects, it just happens that I sometimes get an empty data set back for one of the Series. I could write a handler outside that just tests if either one is empty before trying to join them. But it didn't seem like I should have to.

Comment: As far as merge, it seems like that only handles dataframes, not series. I could use that if I cast both series objects as dataframes. But again, it doesn't seem like I should have to do that. Plus if I have two dataframes, concat works as planned.